# MySQL Select range date between two columns

Tags: php, mysql, date, select

I have the following table (dates) where columns are in date format as defined.

```
id   Column1                Column2       
 1   [2013-07-12 12:00:00]  [2013-07-14 12:00:00]
```

I want to extract the range like this(the dates between column1 and column2):

2013-07-12 12:00:00

2013-07-13 12:00:00

2013-07-14 12:00:00

How to make it possible?

Comment: What do you want the result of the SQL query to be?  The `$result` line doesn't make any sense.  Are you expecting 3 columns for that 1 record or is that a string?

Comment: Im expecting 3 culumns, the 3 dates between 07/12 and 07/14. I hope i'm clear.

Comment: It is nearly impossible to create columns dynamically. But now it looks like you changed your question such that it implies you want rows for each value (which, while easier than columns, is still complicated.)  You may want to focus on a PHP centric solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is PHP script that will take the two dates returned from your table, separate each day, and then put that day into an array.  The dates can then be easily accessed from inside the array.

```
<?php
    $date_1 = date("Y-m-d g:i:s", strtotime('2013-06-27 12:00:00'));
    $date_2 = date("Y-m-d g:i:s", strtotime('2013-07-03 12:00:00'));
    $results = array($date_1);
    $i = $date_1;
    while ($i <= $date_2) {
        $i = date("Y-m-d g:i:s", strtotime("+1 day", strtotime($i)));
        array_push($results, $i);
        echo $i;
    }
    print_r($results);  
?>
```

`$date_1` and `$date_2` will be the values returned from the table.  Be sure you assign the earliest date to `$date_1` or the script will run forever.

Comment: this is exactly what i was looking for to reach my scope. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 3):

Try this one:

```
SELECT * FROM DateTable
WHERE DATEDIFF('2013-07-14',dateFROM)>=0
AND DATEDIFF('2013-07-14', dateTO) <= 0
```

See my [SQLFiddle Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/63c3a/1)

Comment: I appreciated your help this will help

Answer (score 0):

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/date-and-time-functions.html

Maybe do a select * where the datediff between the two columns is less than or equal to your intended range?

Comment: this datediff looks more or less what i'm looking for..give me a time to give you a feedback. thanks..